# .php-fpm-bin 100% CPU usage. How to track the exact script causing it?

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, cpu-usage

I'm hosting a wordpress blog and since 5th of June, I've been having a 100% CPU load (up from 5%), hosted on AWS.

[image]

Now, I've added many plugins, mainly the ones that do 20 mysql queries per page load per user. The problem is that I've added many scripts without realising the load, and I can't disable them.

Ideally, I would change the code, so that the CPU load is restored.

Comment: If you press `c` in top, it shows more details about the command. Does that show you anything useful?

Comment: php-fpm: pool wordpress

Comment: https://www.ecenica.com/support/answer/fix-high-cpu-load-wordpress/  may help. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to break down the CPU by internal PHP processes.

Comment: I've read it, it doesnt help :(

Comment: Can't tell you what exact script does it, but, I have face same issue on Google's compute engine instance that serves bitnami wordpress application and I managed to fix this by restarting the PHP-FPM by: `/opt/bitnami/ctlscript.sh restart php-fpm`.

Answer (score 5):

Something I've seen cause this on wordpress, especially on sites with lots of plugins is `wp-cron.php`. It's a pseudo cron job that runs every request and as it does more and more, these jobs can queue on top of each other, never completing before the next round start and causing the CPU to get out of hand.

In `wp-config.php`, you can disable this by adding the following:

```
define('DISABLE_WP_CRON', true);
```

However this will prevent certain things that were relying on it from working. So you can add a cron to the server to run every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * * wget -q -O - "http://example.com/wp-cron.php" > /dev/null 2>&1
```

If you're unfamiliar with cron, you can add tasks by running `crontab -e` in your server console.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also didn't help

Answer (score 3):

You will probably struggle to pinpoint the issue from top. You could install NewRelic Application Monitoring for PHP. This will highlight slow transactions and give you better insight into what's causing the high load.

I have no affiliation with NR but do use it on all of my servers/applications to good effect. I believe you can try it free for 14 days without a credit card.

Sorry this doesn't answer your issue specifically but hopefully will help you get to the bottom of it.